# DevExpress: индекс в DataTable и Row Handle Id в GridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

Не могу понять, как по индексу в DataTable DataSource получить Row Handle Id в GridView...
(VS2019 C# DX19.2.5 WinForms)

Comment: А зачем вам это понадобилось?

Answer (score 0):

Для сопоставления номеров строк в DataSource с дескрипторами строк в гриде используйте эти методы:

[GridView.GetDataSourceRowIndex](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetDataSourceRowIndex(System.Int32)) - возвращает индекс строки по заданному дескриптору.
[GridView.GetRowHandle](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetRowHandle(System.Int32)) - возвращает дескриптор строки по заданному индексу.

Больше информации можно найти здесь: [Tutorial: Identifying Rows](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114736/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/getting-started/walkthroughs/grid-view-columns-rows-and-cells/tutorial-identifying-rows).